# Python sorted() function and returning multiple values

Tags: c#, python, porting

I am trying to convert a Python program into C#. I do not understand what is being done here.

```
def mincost(alg):
    parts = alg.split(' ')
    return sorted([cost(0, parts, 'G0 '),cost(1, parts, 'G1 ')], key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

def cost(grip, alg, p = '', c = 0.0, rh = True):
    if (len(alg) == 0):
        return (postProcess(p),c)
```

`postprocess` returns a string

`cost` returns multiple parameters used on the sorted() function? How are these multiple values being used by the sorted() function?

what does `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` do? Is this the basis for the sorting, so in this case the multiple value return of `cost` , it will use the value of `c`?

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Refer [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

Comment: @Abhijit , yeah thanks. I should've RTFM

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to duplicate that code exactly. But basically the itemgetter will get the second (item 1) from a list, used here as the sort key. So it will sort on the second item from a list of lists.

Comment: So, just curious, what's the motivation for translating it to C#?

Comment: @Keith, I am more experienced in C# . This program has disappeared from the internet and I would like to add stuff into it and create a frontend GUI. I believe I could do this using Tuples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `sorted` there is a bit weird. You can easily replace that by a simple if-statement. Even weirder though is that `cost` returns just `c` as the second value of the return tuple. In `mincost`, `cost` is never called with a value of `c` that is not the default, so `c` is always `0.0` making the sorting quite redundant. But I guess there are some missing parts about the cost function.

Nevertheless, you could implement it function like this:

```
string MinCost (string alg) {
    List<string> parts = alg.split(" ");
    Tuple<string, double> cost1 = Cost(0, parts, "G0 ");
    Tuple<string, double> cost2 = Cost(1, parts, "G1 ");

    if (cost1[1] < cost2[1])
        return cost1[0];
    else
        return cost2[0];
}

Tuple<string, double> Cost (int grip, List<string> alg, string p="", double c=0.0, bool rh=True) {
    if (alg.Count == 0)
        return new Tuple<string, double>(PostProcess(p), c);

    // ... there should be more here
}
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Thanks @poke, indeed I removed parts of the code. For ``sorted`` , there were more calls to ``cost``, and below ``cost``, there was more code.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then :)